# chrome put an extra quote in myweb site

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

chrome put a quote that **i did not** have in my code.
when I press **F12** in chrome it show me that code.

it cause for a **space** in the top of my website.
because when I delete that quotes , the space disapear and every thing is ok.
chrome show my code like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body>"        
  "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <div class="rsm-header">
```

my code is this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> </head> <body> <div class="rsm-header">
```

Comment: I just tried the code on chrome; works fine; no quotes

Answer (score -1):

Press `ctrl + u` and inspect source. I think you forget remove some debug or something else.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: as I said my code is clear.there is nothing extra in my source code. add yes, I had press Ctrl+u and the source code was clear

Comment: Did it help? If so, its an answer.

Comment: unfortunaly it did not help.